# Split string and add to three columns in datastage

Tags: string, split, delimiter, datastage

I have a column called Name which has the following string:

```
F.M. Brown's Tropical Carnival Small Hookbill, 5-Pound
Kaytee Forti Diet Egg-Cite Food for Parakeets, 5-Pound Bag
```

I wan't to split the string using "," and then by "-" and have it in three columns called Product, Brand & Description. I couldn't find any string split functions that can be used for this. How can I split the string and add them to columns?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: I am using IBM Infosphere datastage

Comment: It doesn't use a language. It's a data warehousing tool by IBM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field(%string%,%delimiter%,%occurrence%,[%number%])

[DataStage Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=functions-field-function)

You should make multiple Stage variables: Product, Brand and Description.

Example:

```
   Product SV: Field (DSLink.Name, “,”, 1, 1)
   Brand   SV: Field (DSLink.Name, “-”, 2, 1)
   Descrip SV: Field (DSLink.Name, “,”, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was asked this in an interview. The answers the web gives is based on space or delimiter but I was asked about one word split into many columns.

E.g.:abcdefghij as input and abcde as col1 and fghij as col2.

So my logic would be to use the beginning of the word till `col1=left(len[str/2]))` for first col and `c0l2=left((len[str/2])+1)` till the rest of the word, inserted as col2.